# discord.py passing a commands parameter or adding a value if parameter is not specified

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to assign a value to the parameter if user doesn't specifies the parameter. I know **"typing.Optional"** but it didn't work(Maybe i don't know how to use it).What i tried to do is if parameter is empty, assign the ctx author to the parameter. Here is how i use it:

```
@client.command()
async def level(ctx, member: typing.Optional = discord.Message.author):
```

Here is what i tried else:

```
@client.command()
async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.message.author
```

and i tried also:

```
@client.command()
async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member = discord.Message.author):
```

When i run this, i got **required parameter** error. So how can i solve it?

Comment: async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):

Comment: That works, i think you should write this to the answers.

Comment: Alright, will do later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python includes support for default values, see [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function-argument)

However the specifics you're looking for are `async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):`

This was recommended to be an answer rather than a comment